# cat filename.* > Datei

Tags: python, cat

I'm looking to translate the unix-command

```
$ cat filename.* > Datei
```

into a Python program. Can somebody help ?

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should get you started:

```
import glob

outfile = file("Datei", "wb")
for f in glob.glob("filename.*"):
  infile = open(f, "rb")
  outfile.write(infile.read())
  infile.close()
outfile.close()
```

**UPDATE**: Of course, input files need to be opened, too.

**UPDATE**: Explicitly use binary mode.

Comment: You forgot to `open()` your input files. `glob.glob` does return a list of file names, not file objects.

Comment: For portability, you should also open your files with in binary mode ('rb', 'wb'). Nasty things will happen on Windows otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

```
import glob

output = open('Datei', 'wb')
chunk_size = 8192
for filename in glob.glob('filename.*'):
    input = open(filename, 'rb')
    buffer = input.read(chunk_size)
    while buffer: # False if buffer == ""
        output.write(buffer)
        buffer = input.read(chunk_size)
    input.close()
output.close()
```

Comment: This might be more efficient than `readlines` since it doesn't have to scan for newline characters.

Answer (score 0):

alternatively

```
import os
f=open("outfile.txt","a")
for file in os.listdir("."):
    if file.startswith("filename."):
         for line in open(file):
               f.write(line)
f.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your help.
My script now:

```
LOGFILEDIR="/olatfile/logs"  
VORMONAT=time.strftime("%Y-%m", time.localtime(time.time()-3600*24*30))  
LOGDATEIEN=LOGFILEDIR+"/olat.log."+VORMONAT +"-*"  
print LOGDATEIEN  
OUTPUT=LOGFILEDIR+"/olat.log."+VORMONAT  
LOGFILE=OUTPUT  
output = open(OUTPUT, 'wb')  
chunk_size = 8096  
for filename in glob.glob(LOGDATEIEN):  
    input = open(filename, 'rb')  
    buffer = input.read(chunk_size)  
    while len(buffer) > 0:  
        output.write(buffer)  
        buffer = input.read(chunk_size)  
    input.close()  
output.close()
```

An application create everyday a logfile like "olat.log.07-12-2009"
My idea was to cat all the logs from one moth into one logfile and analyze this one.